# How to use Goto statement in javascript Imacros

Tags: javascript, label, imacros

I have Imacros code that extract text/data from my php script, my php script is doing well, but it is usually get error because it is pull data from others via API.

So I need to check, are my php script is fully loaded yet, before my Imacros are running. So I need it in javaScript because using "if-else statement" (Imacros not support this), and I very new in Javascript, hope someone can fix my javascript code, here is:

```
var macro;
macro = "CODE:";
macro +="SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO"+"\n";
macro +="SET !DATASOURCE MASTER-ID.txt"+"\n";
macro +="SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 2"+"\n";
macro +="SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}}"+"\n";

macro +="TAB T=1"+"\n";
macro +="URL GOTO=http://localhost/DataGenerator.php?mid={{!COL1}}"+"\n";
macro +="WAIT SECONDS=0.5"+"\n";

macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=B ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT"+"\n";

[lbl] startcheck: //Re-Check Point

for(i=1;i<51;i++){

iimSet("i",i);

var text=null;
var retvalue = iimPlay(macro);

var text = iimGetLastExtract(1);

    if(text=="Warning")   // if my php Script Fail to load , then . .  
    {
            alert("TEXT FOUND"); //for testing purpose 
            alert(text); //for testing purpose

            self.location.reload()'; // this is where i want to reload my webpage
            [lbl] repeat: goto startcheck;  // Jump to Re-Check point  

    }
    else{

     alert("TEXT NOT FOUND"); //for testing purpose
     iimPlay("my-imacros.iim")
}
}
```

Hope some one can fix my javascript code, for "Jump to Re-Check point" and Reload in Javascript, for the worst I will use "iimPlay("reload.iim")" for Reload the page

Comment: I have fix it thanks q All Stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

The OP wrote:

> I have fixed it by myself. The solution is:

```
macro +="WAIT SECONDS=0.5"+"\n";

macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=B ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT"+"\n";


var macrorefresh;
macrorefresh = "CODE:";
macrorefresh +="REFRESH"+"\n";
macrorefresh +="WAIT SECONDS=0.5"+"\n";

for(i=1;i<52;i++){

iimSet("i",i);

var text=null;
var retvalue = iimPlay(macro);

var text = iimGetLastExtract(1);

startcheck:
while(text=="Warning") {
  alert(text); //for testing purpose
  iimPlay(macrorefresh);
 continue startcheck;

}
     alert("TEXT NOT FOUND"); //for testing purpose
     iimPlay("my-imacros.iim")
}
```

> And it WORKS, Thanks you all at Stackoverflow that tried to help me

Comment: ([The answer was edited into the question. Converted to a community Wiki Answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que).)

Answer (score -1):

Does it work like this?

Example:

```
checkpoint:

ret=iimPlay("something.iim");

if(ret<0)
{
break checkpoint;
}
```